# Does Facebook allows to invite user's friends?

Tags: php

Does Facebook allows to invite the user friends on external website? For example accessing a user's friends and send the private message to all of them or email them? Is it considered spam or its allowed?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook's API does not permit messaging users via Facebook messages, nor does it permit retrieval of the e-mail addresses of a user's friends.

You can use the [Requests dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) to invite users' friends to an application, but not an external website.